POSTing JSON objects to server does not work on specific networks, and times out instead
CODE:
    private suspend fun sendJsonFile(file: File) {
        val url = URL(EC2_URL)
        val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        try {
            sendJsonFileLog = "Preparing to send file: ${file.name}"
            // Set timeouts for connection and read operations
            urlConnection.connectTimeout = 50000
            urlConnection.readTimeout = 100000
            urlConnection.requestMethod = "POST"
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
            urlConnection.doOutput = true

            // Read file and compress JSON data
            val jsonInputString = file.readText()
            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            GZIPOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream).use { gzipOutputStream ->
                gzipOutputStream.write(jsonInputString.toByteArray())
            }
            val compressedData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
            sendJsonFileLog = "JSON data compressed"

            // Send compressed JSON data
            urlConnection.outputStream.use { os ->
                os.write(compressedData)
                os.flush()
            }
            sendJsonFileLog = "Compressed data sent"

            // Handle HTTP response codes
            val responseCode = urlConnection.responseCode
            sendJsonFileLog += " - Response code: $responseCode"
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                file.delete()
                sendJsonFileLog += " - File deleted."
                updateList()
            } else {
                handleHttpError(responseCode, urlConnection.responseMessage)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            sendJsonFileLog = "Network error: ${e.localizedMessage}"
            handleNetworkError(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            sendJsonFileLog = "Unexpected error: ${e.localizedMessage}"
            handleUnexpectedError(e)
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect()
            sendJsonFileLog += " - Connection closed."
        }
    }

`
The above android studio Kotlin code works perfectly fine to send JSON objects to an EC2 instance stored application.However, on cellular data on only SOME devices, it won't send at all. No error codes and only timesout when reconnecting to wifi. Any ideas?
Users have tried using the application via wifi to success.
Most Users have success using the application via cellular network,however, some users don't. The user having this issue via cellular network had created similar JSON objects each time to no success via cellular network.

Sounds like a routing/connection in the first place. Not an application issue.

Is the EC2_URL firewalled? (and thus only accessible from some places)
Is it IPv6 only?  (and thus only accessible from IPv6 networks)
If there is some response in a web browser to a GET on EC2_URL that you can use to prove you can route to the server from the client?  If so then have users use that in a web browser on the device... (this will prove/disprove your code has anything to do with it)



It isn't firewalled. EC2_URL is an HTTPS url.
Not IPV6 only to my knowledge as cellular works for some devices.
The URL works fine, it works for some devices just certain devices cellular network is not working.

